# How to access specific rows and columns in a loaded file containing a struct?

Tags: matlab, vector, indexing, struct

I have an assignment, the problem requires accessing data in a loaded file with grades of students in 4 exams for each question: history, biology, science and french.

I tried indexing to get to the grades but just can't understand how to access each row or column of the struct. 
For exemple, if I want the average of grades in the Biology question, how can I access the entire biology column? Or if I want a vector containing the score each student got in question 2 in science.

[image: The struct looks like this after loaded]

I tried to get the biology grade in the following way:

```
B= students(1:1)
c= students(2:2)
d= students(3:3)
e= students(4:4)

m = B.biology
n = c.biology
o = d.biology
p = e.biology

B1 = [m, n ,o, p];
A2 = mean(B1)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To access the entire biology column you should do the following:

```
students(1).biology = [4 4 4 4];
students(1).history = [1 2 3 4];
students(1).science = [20 21 22 23];
students(2).biology = [6 6 6 6];
students(2).history = [5 6 7 8];
students(2).science = [25 26 27 28];

biology_mean = mean([students.biology]);
```

It is important to notice the `[]` to arrange the `students.biology` as a vector that can be used to calculate the mean, for example.

Assuming that element of the struct contains information of one question, you can to access the score each student got in question 2 as follows:

```
students(2).science
```